# Can't fetch data from Sql database for registartion form n login form

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-O72COGQ;Initial Catalog=ClinicManagementtest;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand("select Name ,Password from Registartion_form WHERE Name='" + textBox1.Text + "'and Password='" + textBox2.Text + "'", con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sc );
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)  
            MessageBox.Show("Login Success");
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect login");
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the error you're getting?

Comment: Welcome to the [Sql Injection party](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work). I hope you will not be harmed by this code

Comment: Note this code is subject to Sql injection. Use SqlCommand with parameters instead of concatenation to avoid Sql injection.

Comment: after executing it shows error in da.fill(dt) sql expections was unhandled

Comment: and..? could you post that sqlException? a stack trace?

Comment: Check your tablename, & name , password cannot be empty

Comment: no they are not empty

Comment: The exception message contains also an InnerException with the details of the error. This is the part of your exception that we need to know to be able to help.

Comment: what should i do ??got confused

Comment: @SagarS copy and paste the exception here.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/UcvJn.png @MridulKashyap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it says invalid object name. meaning the table you're trying to use in your sql query is not accessible by your code. can you make sure the table `Registartion_form` exists in the database you're connecting to?

also note, that you have written `Registartion` not `Registration`. notice the typing error "ar" instead of "ra"?

maybe that could be the cause of error. if in your sql server it's `Registration` and not `Registartion`.

Comment: ya thnx there was a spelling mistake thank you so much